# Why can't my Windows Home Server see the internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, windows-home-server

[image]

I've got an ASDL router at home, that is connected via ethernet to a wireless router. My wireless devices at home connect to my wireless network and get access the internet fine.

My Windows Home Server is connect to this same router via an Ethernet connection, but none of the remote features work over the internet.

If I cannot my WHS directly to the ADSL router, then it can see the internet and remote desktop, web server and all that jazz works, but the wireless devices I have on my home network can't see it.

I just don't know enough about networking to know how exactly and when a static route would do the trick or a change to the subnet.

What do I need to do in order to sort out my home network?

**Wireless router**
IP: 192.168.1.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
DHCP: Leave time forever, start IP 192.168.1.100, end IP 192.168.1.200
Firewall: Disabled

**Wireless router: Port forwarding set-up**
192.168.1.101   TCP+UDP 80  Website
192.168.1.101   TCP+UDP 443 website (secure)
192.168.1.101   TCP+UDP 3389    Remote access

**Windows Home Server**
IP: 192.168.1.101

**Additional information**
Attain IP Protocol :     Dynamic IP connect
IP Address  :    192.168.1.65
Subnet Mask  :   255.255.255.0
Default Gateway  :   192.168.1.254
Primary DNS :    8.8.8.8  (Google)
Secondary DNS :      8.8.4.4

Comment: +1 for the diagram. Check the DHCP settings of the wireless router and the adsl router - and add that information to the question - I think it would help to resolve this.

Comment: Attempting to set-up wireless router as per this article: http://www.speedguide.net/read_articles.php?id=2556

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the guide here: [Why can't my Windows Home Server see the internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/111984/why-cant-my-windows-home-server-see-the-internet)

I've disabled DHCP on the wireless router and given it a static IP address outside of the DHCP range of the ADSL router.

Now everything is happy and using the ADSL router as the DHCP server :)

Answer (score 1):

Does the wireless router have a firewall built in?

If so then turn it off and see if you can connect, if you can turn it back on and add rules to the firewall to allow the ports you need to pass through the firewall. If you still cannot access the remote features of your WHS from outside then your problem is more advanced than my network skills sorry.

Hope it helps

Comment: Good question, I don't believe so - but I'll check (All the gear is in my 7 month on sons room, so it's hard to work on!)

Comment: You might find this: http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-6089187.html article good. It has some illustrations to explain sub-netting

Answer (score 1):

Some routers have a DMZ setting, I have a NetGear and I have to set the DMZ server to the same IP address of the Home server, just ping the homeserver name from any machine to determine it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure If I understand correctly, are you saying that you can not access the server remotely once connected to the wireless router?

If that is the case then I would assume that the router has some firewall rules or similar that you would need to consider for allowing traffic in to the server from outside?

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Please add the IP Addresses of your devices and there Gateway/ DNS Addresses to the diagram. I think you see then where your problem is ;)

Comment: I will do this once I'm able to access the router(s). The trouble is all the kit is in my 7 month old son's room, so it restricts when I can access it!

Comment: First things first. Your Windows Home Server has a static IP from the DHCP Pool. This might bee a problem. Second you should look that you only have one DHCP server active. Lastly do the DHCP server publish a valid network config? DNS1 and Gatway should bee the IP of your ADSL Router!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's on the same subnet. Make sure it has a valid route / default route. Make sure the firewall isn't preventing access.

Comment: I think this is part of the problem, but I just haven't got my head round subnets. I read the Wiki article on it, but came out even more confused. Is there a good tutorial you can recommend for me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you mean the Internet can't see your WHS, not that your WHS can't see the Internet (if you Remote Desktop into the WHS, can you access web pages?). If so, you need to look up Port Forwarding for your router(s) if WHS can't use uPnP to set it up automatically. If your router works with uPnP, I believe WHS will set up ports 80, 443, and 4125 to forward.

Comment: When I connected my WHS directly to the ADSL router it did use uPnP to configurate the ports it needed. However looking at the admin, it doesn't seem to tell me what it's done.

Comment: Since you've got two routers in the way, you might be able to let uPnP configure the wireless router and manually set up port forwarding from the ADSL router. But the problem is having two routers in a row -- can you set the wireless router to act as an 'access point' instead of a router? That would make it essentially a switch, and the ADSL router would then be 'directly' connected to WHS.